# SyncFailed Error:Cause: org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/tooling/ModelBuilderService

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a project which I try to open in Android Studio however when the project is imported I receive an error

> Error:Cause: org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/tooling/ModelBuilderService

I searched on google and found that this is a common issue faced on windows. However all the solutions provided are:

1. Delete `.gradle`.
2. `Invalidate Cache/Restart` from `File` in Android Studio.
3. Delete debug folders and files.

Here's what I've tried in addition to the above list.

4. Reinstalled Android Studio.
5. Deleted Android Studio Settings manually from `C:/Users/<username>/.android<>` old directories.
6. Deleted `%temp%` folder.

This project works well in all PCs with Android Studio except this one.

Comment: Can you post the complete log with the exception somewhere?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have added the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

So the problem was solved by deleting the `.gradle` folder. Unfortunately none of the answers that I referred to described which `.gradle` folder I was supposed to delete.

What I did was deleted the `.gradle` folder inside the project structure. What you have to do is delete the `.gradle` folder located in

**Windows:**

```
C:/Users/<username>/.gradle.
```

**MacOS:**

```
~/Users/<username>/.gradle
```

To view hidden files on Mac press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. I had a project running gradle around 0.5.+ that I had to migrate up to 3.1.3.

Comment: for mac os, path is /Users/username/.gradle 
(command + shift + period to show hidden files)

Comment: I just closed the project and reopened and it worked for me. I don't have to delete the folder.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a very simple solution,open your gradle-wrapper.properties file in your project and change your distributionUrl by downgrading/upgrading it.

For example, if gradle 5.1 is giving you problems, you can downgrade to 4.9

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The steps below helped me get out of this situation:

```
Goto -> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart
```

if necessary cleans project and re-build
Thanks!

Comment: This simple step actually resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

On mac use this command to delete .gradle folder.

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following steps:

- Close Android Studio
- Rename .gradle folder
- Open project again

After that Android studio will automatically download `.gradle` folder

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/283877/how-to-delete-files-windows-claims-are-too-long/ Check out this link to delete your long .gradle folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your Android Studio must be 3.4 or above Latest Version.

And Gradle file should be:

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

distributionPath=wrapper/dists

zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

These error comes when you used below Android Studio 3.4 Version.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the IDE to an updated version and remove it as versions that are not available in Android Studio that are on your computer. eg. AndroidStudio2.1 located in C:\Users\

Answer (score 0):

I had also this problem with android studio 3.1.1, it resolved by deleting latest gradle(for me 5.1.1) in `.gradle` folder
I have to mention that `gradle 5.1.1` is not compatible with 3.2 and older

Comment: I am using Android Studio version 3.2.1. How do I find the latest gradle version compatible with my Android Studio version?

Comment: You should go to https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html in this page the best gradles and compatible versions defined but infact finding best compatibility is experimental.You should ask best versions from experts.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

1. Check your build gradle classpath version
2. Open the file `gradle>wrapper>gradlegradle-wrapper.properties` in your project
3. Check the version
4. Use this version in build gradle and sync the project