# Error: Could not build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Error:Could not build

> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.IntelliJSettings

model. Build cancelled.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/46809826/8476022

Comment: Thanks deleting the gradle folder worked for me