# Can't start new projects in Android Studio, Gradle Sync Failed, unable to resolve ExtraModelBuilder

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, synchronization

When I create a new project in Android Studio I'm met with the following in Event Log;

"Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
initialization script 'C:\Users\Jag\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit1.gradle': 4: unable to resolve class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
@ line 4, column 1.
import org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
^
1 error
(3 s 27 ms)"

In the Build: Sync tab it just says;
"Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:"

I can't run anything like this. I haven't even touched the code. I've tried messing with my SDK and Gradle versions, so far with no success. It happens regardless of what activity or minimum SDK I pick. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

[SyncFailed Error:Cause: org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/tooling/ModelBuilderService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791306/syncfailed-errorcause-org-jetbrains-plugins-gradle-tooling-modelbuilderservice)

I can mark my own question as duplicate. Anyway, here's what worked, in that link. I did all of it, not sure what of it worked. I didn't delete android studio debug folders, because I'm not sure what they are.

"Delete .gradle.

Invalidate Cache/Restart from File in Android Studio.

Delete debug folders and files.

Here's what I've tried in addition to the above list.

Reinstalled Android Studio.

Deleted Android Studio Settings manually from C:/Users//.android<> old directories.

Deleted %temp% folder."